# protocol buffers cpp embedded message

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

My .proto file looks like

```
message Cmd
{
      int code =  1;
}

message CmdOne
{
      required Cmd cmd = 1;
      required int data = 2;
}

message CmdTwo
{
      required Cmd cmd = 1;
      required string data = 2;
}
```

In my cpp file, I want to declare objects of `CmdOne` and `CmdTwo` and set both `cmd` and `data` members. But the generated pb.h file does not have a set method for the `cmd` member of `CmdOne` and `CmdTwo` objects, but has a `set` method for the `data` member. How do I set the value of `cmd` for each object?

I don't want to define message `Cmd` inside `CmdOne` and `CmdTwo` messages. I want to reuse the `Cmd` message as I have 10 messages `CmdOne` to `CmdTen`.

Answer (score 23):

You have a couple of different options.  You can get a non-const pointer to the `cmd` field, and then allocate value(s) appropriately:

```
CmdOne cmd_one;
Cmd* cmd(cmd_one.mutable_cmd());
cmd->set_code(2);
// Previous 2 lines could be simplified to:
// cmd_one.mutable_cmd()->set_code(2);
```

Alternativey, if you want to pass a constructed instance of `Cmd` into `CmdOne`, you can do:

```
Cmd* cmd(new Cmd);
cmd->set_code(1);

CmdOne cmd_one;
cmd_one.set_allocated_cmd(cmd);  // Takes ownership of cmd -
                                 // you don't call 'delete cmd'
```

From the "Singular Embedded Message Fields" section of [the docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated):

> Given the message type:
>
> ```
> message Bar {}
> ```
>
> For either of these field definitions:
>
> ```
> optional Bar foo = 1;
> required Bar foo = 1;
> ```
>
> The compiler will generate the following accessor methods:
>
> ...
>
> ```
> Bar* mutable_foo()
> ```
>
> Returns a mutable pointer to the `Bar` object that stores the field's value. If the field was not set prior to the call, then the returned `Bar` will have none of its fields set (i.e. it will be identical to a newly-allocated `Bar`). After calling this, `has_foo()` will return `true` and `foo()` will return a reference to the same instance of `Bar`. The pointer is invalidated by a call to `Clear()` or `clear_foo()`.
>
> ...
>
> ```
> void set_allocated_foo(Bar* bar)
> ```
>
> Sets the `Bar` object to the field and frees the previous field value if it exists. If the `Bar` pointer is not `NULL`, the message takes ownership of the allocated `Bar` object and `has_foo()` will return `true`. Otherwise, if the `Bar` is `NULL`, the behavior is the same as calling `clear_foo()`.

Comment: How can I create a message file like in OP, from my C++ code. I have an input xml file which I parsed using C++ program and have data structures filled in. Is there a way to create a message file automatically from my c++ code? THanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Cmd my_command;

theCommand.set_code(5);

CmdOne cmd_one;

cmd_one.mutable_cmd().copyFrom(my_command);
```

Comment: mutable_[something].copyFrom(other_something) actually copied given data. If you use set_allocated_[something]() for two parent objects, then when one parent dies, it destroys memory behind the child, then when other parent dies, it tries to destroy memory behind the same child, but itś already destroyed. This causes segmentation fault. So copyFrom() worked for me VERY WELL.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is like this:

```
Cmd cmd;
cmd.set_code(1);
CmdOne cmd_one;
*(cmd_one.mutable_cmd()) = cmd;
```